# data.table: delete row following those matching specified condition?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to delete the rows in which volume equals 0, as well as the rows directly below those rows. So, for the df below, I would like to remove rows 3,4 :

```
head(data1)
           open high  low close volume adj.
2013-12-23 6.32 6.36 6.21  6.22 329400 6.22
2013-12-24 6.27 6.36 6.22  6.30 126500 6.30
2013-12-25 6.30 6.30 6.30  6.30      0 6.30
2013-12-26 6.30 6.36 6.23  6.23 126600 6.23
2013-12-27 6.26 6.28 6.20  6.24  54000 6.24
2013-12-30 6.24 6.50 6.24  6.44  61000 6.44
```

I have a solution which works, but is embarrassingly long and sloppy:

```
if.zero.or.not <- as.data.frame(data1$volume == 0)
combined.data = bind_cols(data1, if.zero.or.not )
colnames(combined.data) = c('open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'adj.', 'ifzero')
combined.data.shifted = transform(combined.data,  ifzero = lag(ifzero))
zeros.and.trues.removed = subset(trues.removed, volume != 0, ifzero != T)
```

How can I do this in one or two lines?

Comment: Couldn't you simply use `which`?

Comment: `idx <- which(data1$volume == 0); data1[-c(idx, idx + 1L), ]` (more care may be needed if it's possible for the final row to be 0; perhaps `setdiff(c(idx, idx + 1L), nrow(data1))` is the simplest way)

Comment: @MichaelChirico You should post this as answer.

Comment: I rephrased your question title in generic wording; not to be hung up on any specific language construct like `lead()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write in `data.table` because I prefer the syntax; the translation to `base` is straightforward.

```
library(xts)  #Needed to get the following "xts" "zoo" object
data1 <- structure(c(6.32, 6.27, 6.3, 6.3, 6.26, 6.24, 6.36, 6.36, 6.3, 
6.36, 6.28, 6.5, 6.21, 6.22, 6.3, 6.23, 6.2, 6.24, 6.22, 6.3, 
6.3, 6.23, 6.24, 6.44, 329400, 126500, 0, 126600, 54000, 61000, 
6.22, 6.3, 6.3, 6.23, 6.24, 6.44), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "adj.")), index = structure(c(1387756800, 
1387843200, 1387929600, 1388016000, 1388102400, 1388361600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))

library(data.table)
#setDT fails on "xts" "zoo" object. We need as.data.table
#setDT(data1) #convert to native 'data.table' class _by reference_

data1 <- as.data.table(data1)
data1[if (!length(rows <- -c(idx <- which(volume == 0), (if (volume[.N] == 0) idx[-length(idx)] else idx) + 1L))) TRUE else rows]
```

If you're table is quite large and there are many clustered zeroes, it should be more efficient to wrap `c(...)` in `unique`.

If you've got structural reasons to know the last row won't be zero, this version is easier on the eyes:

```
data1[if (!length(rows <- -c(idx <- which(volume == 0), idx + 1L))) TRUE else rows]
```

---

Comment: @MichaelChirico, sorry to pull you back to this again! I'm getting an error: `Warning message:
In [.data.table(data, if (!length(rows <- -c(idx <- which(volume ==  :
  Item 16 of i is -728 which has occurred before. Ignoring this and 13 other duplicates out of 29.` At first I thought it was ignoring the the fact that there were duplicates, but after reading it again, it looks like it means it is _ignoring operating_ on the duplicates, which is a problem...

Comment: @RyGuy no, actually, it's not. cf. `data.table(a=1:3)[-c(1,1)]`. If you're still not convinced, just surround `c(...)` above with `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.This is an example with a sample data.

```
a  <- c(1,0,9,7,5,0,7,0)
b  <- c(1,9,6,7,4,5,7,8)
dc < -data.frame(a,b)
dc_removed_zero_and_the_next_row <- dc[-c(which(dc$a==0),which(dc$a==0)+1),]
```

Comment: idx <- which(data1$volume == 0); data1[-c(idx, idx + 1L), ] (more care may be needed if it's possible for the final row to be 0; perhaps setdiff(c(idx, idx + 1L), nrow(data1)) is the simplest way) – MichaelChirico 43 mins ago

Comment: note that this computes the index vector twice, which is inefficient unless the `data.frame` is trivially small. also, as I mentioned, you need to deal with the border case -- this will return an error if the last entry is 0.